Google Earth Engine(GEE) exporting a times series raster to table (and then opening it in ArcPro)/ Time series scale too fine
I am working on a project where I am trying to map flooding from 2016-2019 during the months of april-july.I am using the GPM: Global Precipitation Measurement (GPM) v6 from the GEE catalog.
/*
Date Created: 04/16/2024
Last Date modified:  

Original Script from GEE Catalog, GPM: Global Precipitation Measurement (GPM) v6
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NASA_GPM_L3_IMERG_V06#description
*/

// GPM V6 30 minute data around hurricane Dorian for a single day.
// Filter the dataset to select only guyana
var guyana = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Guyana'));

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_V06')
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2019, 'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(4, 8, 'month'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(guyana)) // filter dataset to jut tiles in guyana to reduce computation



//-----------------
//function to filter for maximum precipitation values for each month
var filterMaxPrecipitation = function(dataset) {
  // Select the max precipitation
  //var precipitation = dataset.select('precipitationCal').max();
  
  var precipitation = dataset.select('precipitationCal');
  var maxprecipitation = precipitation.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());
  // Set the threshold for masking low precipitation values
  var threshold = 0.5;
  
  // Create a mask where precipitation values are greater than the threshold
  var mask = maxprecipitation.gt(threshold);
  
  // Apply the mask to the precipitation image
  return maxprecipitation.updateMask(mask);
};
  // Filter the dataset to select only images for the current month
 

// Apply the function to each image in the collection
var maskedPrecipitation = dataset.map(filterMaxPrecipitation);
// --------------------------------


// function to clip each image in the collection
var precipguyanaclip = maskedPrecipitation.map(function(image) {
  return image.clipToCollection(wetlands);
});

var palette = [
  '000096','0064ff', '00b4ff', '33db80', '9beb4a',
  'ffeb00', 'ffb300', 'ff6400', 'eb1e00', 'af0000'
];
var precipitationVis = {min: 0, max: 15, palette: palette};
//Map.addLayer(precipguyanaclip, precipitationVis, 'Precipitation (mm/hr)');
//Map.setCenter(-58.9, 3, 7);


// Visualization parameters for boundary
var styleParams = {
  fillColor: "#00000000", // Transparent fill color
  color: "black",          // Outline color
  width: 2                // Outline width
};

// Style the FeatureCollection
var wetlandsstyled = wetlands.style(styleParams);


// chart a time series
Map.centerObject(wetlands,10);
Map.addLayer(wetlandsstyled, {color: 'black'}, 'Guyana');
Map.addLayer(precipguyanaclip, precipitationVis);


Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: precipguyanaclip,
    description: 'Precip_time_series_Wide',
    folder: 'earthengine',
    fileNamePrefix: 'precip16_19',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
})

/*
// this wont work because..... we need to choose a point for the time series
var l8Chart = ui.Chart.image.series(maskedPrecipitation.select('max'), guyana)
  .setChartType('ScatterChart')
  .setOptions({
   title: 'Precip Time Series in Guyana',
   trendlines: {
     0: {color: 'CC0000'}
   },
   lineWidth: 1,
   pointSize: 3,
  });
print(l8Chart);

*/

//var region = ee.Geometry.BBox(-122.24, 37.13, -122.11, 37.20);


/*
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')
  
  batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(precipguyanaclip, 'test', {
  scale: 30,
  region: guyana
})



Export.image.toDrive({
  image: precipguyanaclip
  description: 'image_export_maxpixels',
  folder: 'gee_guyana',
  region: guyana,
  scale: 30,
  crs: 'EPSG:5070',
  maxPixels: 1e13
}); */

Part of the issue I think is that it tracks precipitation data every half hour, which is way too fine of a scale for my uses, and it create a huge dataset that is way too large to view using the chart in GEE. Therefore I have been trying to export it to a table so I can open it in ArcPro... as suggested in this Spatial thoughts time series tutorial. My table however looks nothing like theirs. Here's a picture of my table:
my exported table.
So if anyone has any suggestions on how to to further reduce the time series so that it has one image for each week instead of each half hour... that would be great. Thanks for the help!
